# Spring Integration context file, is there any file to list all the related attributes

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

This question comes to me when I want to add a **fixed-rate** for **outbound-gateway**.

I need to know the available **attributes** for each **integration** module.

And yes I have the API Doc and Refs doc.

And I even checked the **spring-integration(-*).xsd** file.

But they are all not that helpful.

I think there should be a javaDoc like *attributesDoc*.

Is there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Spring integration reference manual is pretty exhaustive and covers all the attributes for each "integration module". As an alternative if u are using Eclipse or IntelliJ using ctrl + space inside of the xml definition should list you the attributes you can select for that node.

Comment: Thx @Beard, This is helpful.